# Expansion of $(1+X)^b$ when $b \in \mathbb{Z}_p$ and $b \notin \mathbb{N}$

Tags: reference-request, binomial-coefficients, p-adic-number-theory

For each $b \in \mathbb{N}, (1+X)^b=\sum\limits_{n=0}^b{{b}\choose {n}}X^{n}$ which is a polynomial in $X$. Do we have any expansions like that if $b \in \mathbb{Z}_p$ and $b \notin \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: What meaning can you give to $(1+X)^b$ when $b\notin \Bbb{Z}$ ?

Comment: How about $\exp_p(b\log_p(1+X))$ where $\exp_p$ and $\log_p$ are $p$-adic exponential and logarithm?

Comment: Thanks for explanation. Great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is certainly valid for odd $p$ as long as $X\in p\Bbb Z_p$.

Comment: The sum will now be infinite i.e. $n $ will go from $0$ to $\infty$?

Comment: Yes, indeed!...

Comment: Could you answer Max's question in the comments?

Answer (score 2):

If $\{a_n\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ is a sequence in $\mathbb{Q}_p$ (or in any complete extension thereof) such that $a_n \rightarrow 0$, then the **Mahler series**

$x \mapsto  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n {x \choose n}$

converges uniformly on $\mathbb{Z}_p$ and (thus) defines a continuous function.  (The converse is also true: **Mahler's Theorem**.) See [here](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/8410FULL.pdf) for an exposition of Mahler series.  The convergence claim is the (easy) Lemma 4.1.3.

If $a_n = X^n$ for $X \in \mathbb{Z}_p$, then $a_n \rightarrow 0$ iff $X \in p \mathbb{Z}_p$.  Since $\mathbb{N}$ is dense in $\mathbb{Z}_p$, this is the unique continuous extension to $\mathbb{Z}_p$, i.e., if anything deserves to be called $(1+X)^b$, this function does.

(If $X \in \mathbb{Z}_p \setminus p\mathbb{Z}_p$, the series does not converge for $b = -1$.)